# C/C++ program crashes on bubblesort

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

I have an array of structs with different datatypes, I want to sort my array on the floats of my structs, from least to greatest... 
my program runs fine, however when I do my bubblesort to sort the array of structs, the program crashes or does not respond anymore..here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


struct Stud{
        long matrnr;
        char vorname[30];
        char name[30];
        char datum[30];
        float note;
    };



void sortieren(Stud mystud[], int studentCounter) {
Stud tmp;   
for (int i = 0 ; i< studentCounter; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j< studentCounter-1;  ++j) {
        if (mystud[j].note > mystud[j+1].note) 
        {
                tmp = mystud[j+1];
                mystud[j+1] = mystud[j];
                mystud[j] = tmp;
            }           
        }
    }       
}           


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   


    const int MAX = 30;
    Stud stud;  
    Stud mystud[30]; // <<-- Array of "Stud" type
    //memset((void*)mystud,0,sizeof(mystud) * sizeof(Stud));
    int wordCounter(0);
    int i(0); //thats the charCounter or index
    int studentCounter(0);
    char wort[MAX];
    //int matrnr;
    //char vorname[MAX];
    //char name[MAX];
    //char datum[MAX];
    //float note;
        ....
....
....
....
```

Comment: Is this an exercise, or are you interested in the easiest way to sort your array?

Comment: Do you realize that you are not moving entire student records but rather just copying your `note` field around?

Comment: did you debug? where does it crash? run in the debugger and check the values of `i`, `j`, `studentCounter` and of course the elements of the array. beware that you are not swapping elements of the array, you are only swapping the `note` value of two elements of the `mystud` array.

Comment: this is an exercise but yes, I'm interested in the easiest way to sort my array ,... @StevenBurnap oops , I see it now lol... that's so stupid..edit : I updated it now in the code, but it still crashes...

Comment: hmmm can I assign Stud tmp = mystud[something] or do I have to assign them value by value again???

Comment: You need to use `strncpy` or something like it.  Your crash itself is likely caused by the way the value of `studentCounter` is determined and/or how memory is allocated for `mystud`.  But this is all code review stuff, not really appropruate for this site.

Comment: yeah u're right, the error was that I had to assign every value in the struct to its value in the corresponding array , and I accidently passed the counter wordCunt passed instead of studentCount...

Answer (score 0):

thats how it worked:

```
void sortieren(Stud mystud[], int studentCounter) {
Stud tmp;   
for (int i = 0 ; i< studentCounter; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j< studentCounter-1;  ++j) {
        if (mystud[j].note > mystud[j+1].note) 
        {
                tmp.matrnr = mystud[j+1].matrnr;
                strcpy(tmp.vorname,mystud[j+1].vorname);
                strcpy(tmp.name,mystud[j+1].name);
                strcpy(tmp.datum , mystud[j+1].datum);
                tmp.note = mystud[j+1].note;

                mystud[j+1].matrnr = mystud[j].matrnr;
                strcpy(mystud[j+1].vorname ,mystud[j].vorname);                 
                strcpy(mystud[j+1].name , mystud[j].name);
                strcpy(mystud[j+1].datum ,mystud[j].datum);
                mystud[j+1].note = mystud[j].note;

                mystud[j].matrnr = tmp.matrnr;
                strcpy(mystud[j].vorname , tmp.vorname);
                strcpy(mystud[j].name , tmp.name);
                strcpy(mystud[j].datum , tmp.datum);
                mystud[j].note = tmp.note;                  

            }           
        }
    }       
}
..
...
...
...

sortieren(mystud , studentCounter);
```